# problem in jquery dataPicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am getting the following error while choosing date from date picker

> Microsoft JScript runtime error:
>   'length' is null or not an object

It gives error in WebResource.axd file at line, at some loop that says,

```
for(i=0;i<vals.length;i++)
{
    alidatorvalidate(vals,null,length);
}
```

I have included the following scripts to my page

1. jquery-1.6.1.min.js
2. jquery-datePicker.js
3. jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css
4. jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js
5. jquery.datePicker.min-2.1.2.js`

what could be wrong? i have not much idea about jquery
its all going confusing.can i have idea how to implement jquery datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

Heena you don't need `jquery-datePicker.js` and `jquery.datePicker.min-2.1.2.js` as you are using `jquery-ui`.

Try this. Suppose you have a textbox like this.

```
<input type="text" id="mypicker" />
```

Use this script

```
<link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="">
    $(function() {
        $( "#mypicker" ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: it shows calender but without any formatting.i mean just digits of dates and Prev and Next written. am I missing anything so that it show formatted?