# problem implementing jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

can i get what are the total plugin require to implemet jquery date picker and from where can i get them all?
right now i m using,

datePicker.css

jquery.datePicker.js

jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js

jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css

can any one suggest me?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320086/problem-in-jquery-datapicker delete this post or duplicate post. otherwise, you will get a down vote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean [this datepicker?](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/). If so, it is part of the jQuery UI, so it will be provided in the jquery-ui file. However, each jquery-ui file can be customised to include (or not) various parts of the UI. You'll need to make sure that you've included it when you selected the components of your custom jquery-ui bundle on their [download page](http://jqueryui.com/download). You can always download it again to make sure. Inside the downloaded zip file will be an example html document that contains the includes you'll need:

`css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.css`

`js/jquery-1.5.1.min.js`

`js/jquery-ui-1.8.13.custom.min.js`

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your missing jQuery itself, which everything else depends on. Make sure you include it before the plugin. For a more helpful answer, include your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery UI [date picker documentation is here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

Answer (score 0):

Normally I get by with just the jquery-ui .js and .css, but you need make sure that you have included the datepicker when you customised the jquery, else simply use the full jquery-ui library.